# "Powder" from Github not installing (RStudio)

Tags: r, github

I'm trying to run this piece of code from a Github read.me file

````
## Install
```{r,eval=FALSE}
#install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('jeff324/powder',build_vignettes = TRUE)
```
````

However. I keep getting this error message back in the console:

```
Downloading GitHub repo jeff324/powder@HEAD
Installing 1 packages: tibble
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/tessc/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/tibble_3.0.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 836388 bytes (816 KB)
downloaded 816 KB

package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error: Failed to install 'powder' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘tibble’
>
```

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: Likely because the tibble package is currently loaded in your environment. Restart your R session and try again.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I do when I get these types of errors is to Restart R.  Go to Session -> Restart R.  If that doesn't work, try opening a brand new session in R Studio.  I was just able to install this package. So fundamentally, it is working.